# Why can't I change tick values in seaborn clustermap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

```
import seaborn as sns
matrix = [[8,1,3],[4,6,5],[2,11,6]]
ax = sns.clustermap(matrix)
for l in ax.ax_heatmap.axes.get_xticklabels():
    l.set_text('c')
    l.set_color('g')
```

I want to change all the labels in my clustermap. Weirdly the color changes but the text doesn't

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. That means that we can try your code. Right now we can't because we don't know what the variable matrix contains. You don't have to provide your actual values, just some that cause the same problem.

Comment: I added a matrix that causes the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import seaborn as sns
matrix = [[8,1,3],[4,6,5],[2,11,6]]
ax = sns.clustermap(matrix)
new_labels = []
for l in ax.ax_heatmap.axes.get_xticklabels():
    l.set_text('c')
    l.set_color('g')
    new_labels.append(l)
ax.ax_heatmap.axes.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Though I don't understand why the color does change but the text does not in your example. Hopefully someone who understands seaborn better than I do can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is changing the tick label color it goes like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
matrix = [[8,1,3],[4,6,5],[2,11,6]]
ax = sns.clustermap(matrix,figsize=(5,5))
for l in ax.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels():
    l.set_color('green')
for l in ax.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels():
    l.set_color('green')
```

[image]